# Thread dump in Objective C

Tags: xcode

I am new into objective c and I want to analyse my current thread.In java we using Using Thread Dumps. What is equivalent in objective C?

Comment: What does "analyze" mean? The call stack? Beside this, in Objective-C it is common to use dispatch queues (or the cocoa equivalent `NSOperationQueue`).

Comment: I need to get stack trace of thread execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[NSThread callStackSymbols]` will give you the call stack backtrace. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

The reference is at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the stack in Xcode. The stack trace is always related to one point in time of execution. So you have to set a break point to the location you want to see the stack trace.

Xcode automatically switches to the debug navigator, if lldb stopped execution because of a break point. To switch manually click on the 6th symbol from the right at the top of the navigators.

To learn more about debugging refer this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html).